# android manifest not loading pages correctly

Tags: android, android-manifest

Hi I am working on an android app when it starts a splash screen appears.  After that it is suppose to go into a login screen where user can login or signup to login.

The issue i am having is that once the splash screen loads it skips the login activity and goes straight to main activity of my app.  I am pretty sure its something to do with my manifest but not sure what I need to do.

manifest

```
<application
    android:name=".AppController"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >


    <activity
        android:name=".SplashScreen"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SignupActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
     </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".EventDetails"
        android:label="@string/title_eventDetails">

    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".EventDateSet"
        android:label="@string/guest_list">

    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".EventTimeSet"
        android:label="@string/guest_list">

    </activity>
            </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: The manifest looks fine except you have an unmatched closing tag at the bottom. In your LoginActivity, you must be launching the MainActivity. The system doesn't launch your Activities automagically.

Comment: @hozdaman The manifest file will specify which activities are present in the app and which is the launcher activity. As you have mentioned in the manifest file, Splash is launched and in that activity you should be writing code to go properly to LoginActivity. If you can post that logic also, we will be able to give some feedback as to why it is directly going to your MainActivity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a clean version of your manifest, as @WindsurferOak said you have an unmatched closing tag.

```
<application
    android:name=".AppController"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >


    <activity
        android:name=".SplashScreen"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SignupActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
     </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".EventDetails"
        android:label="@string/title_eventDetails">

    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".EventDateSet"
        android:label="@string/guest_list">

    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".EventTimeSet"
        android:label="@string/guest_list">

    </activity>

</application>
```

Comment: Thank you @WindsurferOak   both of those were my issues.  Once corrected the app loaded correctly.

Comment: You're most welcome, will you please accept my answer.